# how to read a file, sort based on specified column

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to convert all my codes, written in MATLAB, to python. I have a problem and I couldn't find a way to solve it. Maybe someone has an idea.

I have a file which has m rows and two columns. I want to read file, and then sort file based on the second column. Later, I must use the sorted first column (from first row to 1000th row) and find values larger than threshold (here for example 0.2) and sum them.

Hope someone has an idea.
Thanks

Comment: You have to read files, and create `list` from files data. On list you can perform operation like `sort` etc. If you want to write back sorted data, you can write to same file.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: if you are going from matlab to the python world, then I suggest you use SciPy.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is for example with fields separated by tabs and rows separated by columns the problem is quite simple:

```
f = open("filename.csv")
data = [map(float, x.split("\t")) for x in f.readlines()]
data.sort(key = lambda x:x[1])
result = sum(x[0] for x in data[:1000] if x[0] > 0.2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Except one problem in summation, it works. I know from my MATLAB codes, that the sum of values larger than threshold is, for example 56. But after following this code, the value is 59! I checked for other files, and what I found is that the differences between results vary between 2 to 4! Do you have any idea, what might be the reason? Thanks again.

Comment: @Samira: one possibility is that there are multiple rows with the same value on the second column, so which rows ends up being in the first 1000 can be different for Python and Matlab (Python sort is stable, I don't know about Matlab sort algorithms).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Numpy arrays and its accompanying functions. They are (usually) quite similar to those in MATLAB, which might make your conversion from the latter easier.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtext("filename.csv", delimiter="\t", dtype=np.float)
idx = np.argsort(data[:, 1])
data1000 = data[idx[:1000]]  # First 1000 of sorted data
result = np.sum(data1000[data1000[:, 0] > 0.2, 0])
```